# How to compare Google Maps coordinates on an accurate way?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the coordinates(lat, lng) and the information associated to this point in an excel sheet. 
I want to compare the coordinates that I have stored on a database(lat, lng) with the excel ones. 
My main idea is to show the correct info about the road point on the info window associated to the marker. 
My doubt is about how to choose the coordinates on the most accurate way?.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You have to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean, "how to choose the coordinates on the most accurate way"? You say you have one data set in Excel and another in a database, do you mean that you want help figuring out which data set to use?

Comment: Sorry about I was not really specific when I wrote the text. I´ll try to explain all the idea: I have an Android app that get the user´s coordinates, and I store that data on an oracle database. My company gaves me coordinates of roads and information associated to that coordinates. So I must try to find the better way to compare both kind of coordinates and associate the information to the coordinates on Oracle´s database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I understand what you are doing - capturing the coordinates of a user's location and then you want to find information about what is nearby to that location. If I have that correct, I suggest you take a look at the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Google provides a library/service that allows you to send a `request`that includes a location and radius or coordinates that define a rectangular bounds and the service will return information about nearby places of interest. There are many ways to refine the searches to focus on different types of features.

I think this is what you are looking for - if not, provide a little more detail and I will try to help you.

Comment: Yes!, it´s perfect, now I have an orientation! :)